# django distinct() and order_by() extra() use together

Tags: python, django

I use django restframwork

this is a function in views.py when link to `127.0.0.1/movie/?top=1`

I want to query the movie still on theater and the releaseday within 1 month
But sometimes the result will duplicate ,
Please help me to check my query why would this happen??

```
def top(self):
    past_month.date() = '2014-12-20'
    today.date()      = '2015-01-20'
    self.queryset = Movie.objects.filter(releaseday__gte=past_month.date(),releaseday__lte=today.date(),movie__showtime__gte=today).extra({'vrank': 'CASE WHEN hot=0 THEN 21 WHEN hot >=10 THEN 21 ELSE hot END'}).order_by('vrank','-releaseday').distinct()
```

This is my model :

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    releaseday      = models.DateField( null=True,blank=True)           

class MovieShowtime(models.Model):
    movie           = models.ForeignKey( Movie, null=True,blank=True,related_name = 'movie' )
    movietime       = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is probably the case that your query is returning distinct rows, but the differences between some rows are only in columns that you don't intend to look at (e.g., a field in a related table).

To be sure that your query returns distinct values for the columns you care about, use .values(['col1', 'col2' ...]) just before distinct().

Also be sure to see the note in the docs here about ordering on columns that aren't included in values(): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#distinct

Comment: I use valie will have this problem ````'dict' object has no attribute 'datetime'````   because I deal with datetime in serialize.py

Comment: @user2492364 I'm not sure how to help with that and it sounds like a different problem. Perhaps that's a different SO question with code and traceback?

Comment: Thank you for helping me! I found why would it happened. Because I need to pass queryset to serialize.py to do things,so I can't use ````values```` it will become dict.I still find another method to fix this.